# How to install invoceninja with docker hub on a Synology NAS

Tags: docker, synology, invoice-ninja

I am very new with invocenija and docker. I never used Docker yet. I would like to install invoceninja on my synology NAS. On my NAS I already installed Container manager, and I downloaded [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/invoiceninja/invoiceninja/).

I suppose I should now create a container
[Docker - Create Ninja Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjJMj.png)
and may be I get all ready. Does the PHP8.1 and MySQL or Maria DB are in the container, or should I install its on my NAS, before

However, I also red the prerequisite [here bellow](https://hub.docker.com/r/invoiceninja/invoiceninja)

About the following command, I should ssh my NAS from my Mac and run the following command, isn't? Or should I do it in my container

```
docker run --rm -it invoiceninja/invoiceninja php artisan key:generate --show
```

About the following folders, same question as above, should it be on my NAS or the container

> /var/invoiceninja/public

> /var/invoiceninja/storage

Many thanks for your help